How to generate the smallest circle engulfing 3 random circles?
I would like to generate this type of circle on the 2d Cartesian coordinate system.
Initially i tried to break the problem into a simpler version first which led me to assume 3 equal circles.
The way to do this for 3 equal circles is straightforward- find the circle passing throught the 3 centres and then extend its rardius by the radius of the equal circles.
But i am unable to do so with proving that this is the smallest possible one for 3 random circles of unequal radius.

Even for three circles of equal radius, your construction doesn’t give the smallest circle. Think about the case when the three centres are collinear.

@Pranay - that is related to the circumcircle of an obtuse-angled triangle not being its minimum bounding circle

@Pranay that is correct and i am unable to think of another way, but for circles with non collinear centres it still seems to be the smallest? as we are basically finding the circumcircle of the triangle made by the centres and then extending that by the minimum possible amount.

Take a look at @Henry’s comment. Being collinear isn’t the only issue. I gave that example only to explain why your construction doesn’t always give the right answer.

@Pranay my apologies! Ty

Note that "random" doesn't seem like appropriate terminology here. I think you meant "any" instead.

What exactly do you mean by generate? Do you want a bunch of equations whose solution gives you the coordinates of the centre and the radius of the circle? Or do you want a purely Euclidean geometric construction?

@FrançoisMortier by random i meant to imply that the 3 circles have any possible random centre, radius.

@Pranay i think the equation of a circle which satisfies the conditions states on 3 circles with (g,h) & (a,b) & (x,y) and radii r1 r2 r3

@Scypher_Tzu I got what you meant, but "random" is simply not the appropriate word.
